# Using PKCE with laravel/passport always returns error:"invalid_client" message:"Client authentication failed"

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, nuxt.js, pkce

I'm using laravel/passport v9.4.0 with laravel 7 to implement authentication on my Nuxt SPA. I've opted to use the [PKCE](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport#code-grant-pkce) flow for security but for some reason I'm only getting this response from the server:

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client authentication failed","message":"Client authentication failed"}
```

I've used the following command to create the client:

```
passport:client --name=PKCE --public --no-interaction
```

and I can see it in the database so I know I'm using the correct client id. I'm using @nuxt/auth and my authorization url looks like this:

http://mycompany.localhost/oauth/authorize?protocol=oauth2&response_type=code&access_type&client_id=11&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmycompany.localhost%3A3000%2Flogin&scope=openid%20profile%20email&state=pU5qdCyPuA&code_challenge_method=S256&code_challenge=qun17_MpZibssRR672w8kVpZpaUynGdkHy3_LrGudBc

I'm also using the [stancl/tenancy](https://github.com/stancl/tenancy) package as it's a multi-tenant app but that shouldn't be an issue as the queries all look ok. I've also tried without @nuxt/auth, as per [this tutorial](https://dev.to/stefant123/pkce-authenticaton-for-nuxt-spa-with-laravel-as-backend-170n) but still the same result.

Is it an incompatibility between passport and laravel 7? The laravel 7 docs detail how to use PKCE with passport so not really sure what the issue is here.

Answer (score 0):

the 'redirect' column in the client was incorrect. Because I'm using npm run dev for my frontend, it should have been http://localhost:3000. Passport defaulted it to my homestead hostname.

Comment: According to documentation if you would like to allow multiple redirect URLs, define multiple redirects by comma. Any URLs which contain commas should be URL encoded: `http://example.com/callback,http://examplefoo.com/callback`

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport - Redirect URLs section